# GoogleサイトにGoogleフォームの事前入力したURLへのリンクを設置したい。

Tags: html, google-sites

タイトルの通りGoogleサイトにGoogleフォームの事前入力したURLを利用したリンクを設置したいのですが、
普通に作成して保存するとなぜかjavascript:void(0);へのリンクにされてしまいます。
調べてみると一応Googleサイトに外部リンクを設置することはできるらしいのですが、
どうすれば設置できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

フォームのURLをgasで作成するときの日本語のエスケープ方法がよくなかったようです。

・リンクが変換される例
%u+4文字形式(%u904Bなど)
・リンクが変換されない例
%+2文字(%E6など)

対策
escapeで日本語をエンコードすると%u+4文字形式にされてしまうので、
encodeURIかencodeURIComponentを使用する。